# HBase regions not fail over correctly, stuck in "OPENING" RIT

Tags: hbase, high-availability

I am using the hbase-2.2.3 to setup a small cluster with 3 nodes.  (both hadoop and HBase are HA mode)

```
node1: NN, JN, ZKFC, ZK, HMaster, HRegionServer
node2: NN, JN, ZKFC, DN, ZK, Backup HMaster, HRegionServer
node3: DN, JN, ZK, HRegionServer
```

When I reboot node3, it cause the regions-in-transaction (some regions are in OPENING).
In the master log, I can see: `master.HMaster: Not running balancer because 5 region(s) in transition`

Anyone know how to fix this issue? Great thanks

Comment: I found that when I kill the DataNode on node3, it also will cause Regions in Transaction when the cluster try to do region load balancer again,  and it also stuck put data to some table, and stuck create new table.  When I reboot all of the region servers, the issue is gone. But I don't want to reboot any service.   Is there any setting change to avoid this issue?